# How to do optimization of the Dictionary and while loop

Tags: dictionary, optimization, while-loop, swift3, runtime

I am solving task in the hackerrank site and receive interesting `Runtime Error` that is connected with amount of data that is placed in the test.

Task:

> Given  names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps
>   friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be
>   given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For
>   each  queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a
>   new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for  is not found,
>   print Not found instead.

My solution:

```
let n = Int(readLine()!)! //Amount of tests
let count = n * 2//Insertion to the dictionary and validation of the data

var step = 0
var book = Dictionary<String, String>(minimumCapacity: n)

while step < count {
    if (step < n ) {
        let bookData = readLine()!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        book[bookData[0]] = bookData[1]
    } else {
        let name = readLine()!
        if let num = book[name] as String! {
           print("\(name)=\(num)")
        } else {
           print("Not found")
        }
    }
    step += 1
}
```

I am interested in optimization of the code to avoid `Runtime Error`. I already do some adjustments they are connected with `minimumCapacity` of the `Dictionary` and usage of the `while` instead of `for-loop`. Could you please advise what should be fixed?

Comment: "optimization" and "avoid Runtime Error" are two different tasks. Is your program *too slow* for Hackerrank or does it terminate with *errors*?

Comment: @MartinR all test cases are running well except one that contain 100000 elements this test produce Runtime Error

Comment: How does your code handle the *"**unknown number** of names to query"*? You seem to assume that entries are followed by the *same amount* of queries.

Comment: @MartinR you are right and that is a point. Please post you notice as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input data consists of a *fixed part* (number `N` of entries,
followed by `N` lines of name/number pairs) and a *variable part*
(the queries).

You can use forced unwrapping `readLine()!` for the fixed part because
you *know* that it will succeed. But for the variable part you have
to call `readLine()` until it returns `nil`.

The code would then look like this:

```
let n = Int(readLine()!)! // Number of entries
var book = [String: String](minimumCapacity: n)

for _ in 1...n {
    let bookData = readLine()!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    book[bookData[0]] = bookData[1]
}

while let name = readLine() {
    if let num = book[name] {
        print("\(name)=\(num)")
    } else {
        print("Not found")
    }
}
```